# sql query (sum) result show on jlable

Tags: java, sql, odbc

I want to calculate sum from "amount" column of "transaction" table and I want to show the result on jLable1. I write this code but when I run the file. It show the message. I use ms access database.

"java.sql.SQLException:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]Invalid cursor state".

Someone please give a suggestion.

```
String sql="SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transaction";
try
        {
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rst=pst.executeQuery();


    long bal=rst.getLong(1);
            jLable1.setText(""+bal);

}
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

        }
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/ Did you read about jdbc at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29):

> A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the
>   first call to the method next makes the first row the current row

You should first invoke `rs.next()` and then get some of it's elements. For example:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    long bal=rst.getLong(1);
    ...
}
```